# What does "talking past one another" mean?

Tags: expressions

In the following sentence:

> In fact, the two sides are talking past one another if they focus on how strict zero-covid policies are.

What does "talking past one another" mean?

Comment: Ok, so the example sentence is weak, but the phrase doesn't require an example.  Yet another good question closed for no apparent reason, with no explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Jack O'Flaherty kindly provided the source ([chinastrategy.org](https://chinastrategy.org/2021/11/12/china-will-stick-to-a-zero-covid-policy-for-now/)) of your sentence in a comment below. I read the "**if** they focus" in your sentence as "**when** they focus/ **by** focusing."

**talking past each other**

> **Talking past each other** is an English phrase describing the situation where two or more people talk about different subjects,
> while believing that they are talking about the same thing. [Google
> Arts & Culture](https://artsandculture.google.com/entity/talking-past-each-other/m0ds210b?hl=en)

**talk past each other / talk past someone**

> A situation where two or more people talk about different subjects
> while believing they are talking about the same thing.
>
> *In American politics the left and the right simply talk past each other without having any real dialogue.*
>
> *I know my parents' marriage is going to end in divorce—they constantly talk past each other.*
>
> *Our company brought in an outside expert who found we were talking past our customers rather than having a real dialogue.*
>
> *It's really important for parents to try to improve communication with their teenagers because it's very easy to talk past one
> another.* [oysterenglish.com](https://www.oysterenglish.com/idiom-talk-past-each-other.html)

---

> But the antebellum political worldviews often **talked past one
> another**, Whig confidence in a prudent, prosperous future making
> little sense to wary Jacksonians, skeptical of vague promises of a
> better tomorrow seemingly, to their eyes at least, at the expense of a
> comfortable, independent today. [Joseph Pearson; *The Whig's
> America*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Whigs_America/ZG_dDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22talked%20past%20one%20another%22&pg=PA29&printsec=frontcover)

> At the root of it, however, he believes there lies a "**failure in
> communications**," that "the debaters have **talked past one another**";
> that "Woodward and his critics do seem to be **discussing different
> problems**." He goes on to observe that "the revisionists are talking
> mostly about practice and attitudes, Woodward about political rhetoric
> and law; they about social and economic structure, he about political
> and ideological superstructure."  [Comer Vann Woodward; *The Future of
> the Past*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Future_of_the_Past/A4aG34ywu1AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22talked%20past%20one%20another%22&pg=PA304&printsec=frontcover)

---

A related idiom is

**be/talk at cross purposes**

> (of two people or groups) misunderstand what the other is referring to
> or trying to do: *Mary and I spoke about Anne for a minute or two
> before I realized we were talking at cross purposes: I meant Anne
> Smith and Mary meant Anne Harris.* [Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/talk+at+cross+purposes)

An instance of this happened to me when I was living in Italy. I was at the counter in a cafe having coffee with an acquaintance. We were talking about our jobs and I used the word *salary* and he suddenly interrupted: *How much?* I was flustered by his asking so directly and I said something vague about my salary. He repeated the question more emphatically. We went back an forth a bit until I realized his hand was holding a spoonful of sugar from the counter's bowl over my espresso cup.

Comment: I'm not sure that OP's example works. The conditional seems difficult to integrate.

Comment: I'll ask for more detail.

Comment: Here's the source: https://chinastrategy.org/2021/11/12/china-will-stick-to-a-zero-covid-policy-for-now/

Comment: @Jack Good sleuthing. And a very interesting article.

Comment: Ah: given the original, I'd say 'are sidestepping the major issue' fits better. But a good answer to the title question.

Comment: A key point is that the people could be intentionally talking past one another for selfish reasons, like to make the other person sound dumb or win a political argument (talk 'around' an issue with something they feel is correct, but which does not address the fundamental question); or completely unaware they're talking past each other, like in the excellent example about sugar.